# MYSQL group by sum when there are nulls

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a group summation in mysql , but the nulls are causing issue. I used nullif/ifnull none helped

Here is an example

```
 Group  Employee  Discipline  HardWork  Dedication
 101    DTF           1            1             1
 101    Tim             1             1            0
 101    Erk             NULL       1            0
 101    PMD           NULL       1            0
 101    NSE           1             1            0
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    GROUP,
    SUM( EMPLOYEE ),
    SUM( DISCIPLINE ),
    SUM( HARDWORK ),
    SUM( DEDICATION )
FROM
    TABLE
GROUP BY
    GROUP,
    EMPLOYEE,
    DISCIPLINE,
    HARDWORK,
    DEDICATION
```

Expected result:

```
101---3----5----1
```

Actual result

```
101--5----5-----1
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Your query is meaningless, you can't `SUM` a text column value, and `SUM`ing the same columns you're performing a `GROUP BY` on will only result in 1 value for each aggregate. Do you perhaps mean `COUNT` instead?

Comment: The `NULL` values aren't a problem for the `SUM()` aggregate. The query returns five expressions in the SELECT list, what's reported as "actual results" only shows four columns. Given the sample data and the query, we would expect the query to return *five* rows, not a single row, because of the expressions in the GROUP BY clause. You're barking up the wrong tree about the `NULL` values "causing issue".

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`SUM(IFNULL( Discipline, 0 ))`

instead of

`SUM( DISCIPLINE )`

The firt one will take the value 0 is a null is found.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be:

```
SELECT
    Group,
    COUNT( Employee ) AS EmployeeCountInGroup,
    SUM( ISNULL( Discipline, 0 ) ) AS SumDiscipline,
    SUM( ISNULL( HardWork, 0 ) ) AS SumHardWork,
    SUM( ISNULL( Dedication, 0 ) ) AS SumDedication
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    Group
```

Comment: i tried this approach , by the way ISNULL is not a mysql thing, IFNULL but its not giving expected count